# How can I see a varibles value when my plugin runs?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, variables

I am trying to make a plugin that redirects a user based on how they fill out a form. I am having trouble finding my problem I have narrowed it down to a small snippet that seems to work.

```
function cf7pp_after_send_mail( $contact_form ) {

    global $postid;

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $postid = $posted_data['_wpcf7'];

        $enable = get_post_meta( $postid, "_cf7pp_enable", true);
        $email = get_post_meta( $postid, "_cf7pp_email", true);

        $valuepassed = get_post_meta($post_id, "_cf7pp_text_menu_b", true);

        if ($enable == "1") {
            if ($valuepassed == "1") {
                if ($email == "2") {

                    include_once ('includes/redirect.php');

                    exit;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change:

```
if ($valuepassed == "1")
```

to

```
if ($valuepassed == "0")
```

The behavior changes to not redirect which is great but I want to see what value is being passed to $valuepassed because I have not been able at this point to make it behave dynamically like it should. I want to see if something completely unexpected is being passed.

Comment: `die( $valuepassed );`

Comment: That worked to show me that I have nothing, however I tried looking at other variables and they also show nothing. I am really not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: I would try `die(print_r( $posted_data, true ) );` right before `$postid=...` to make sure you are accessing correct fields. Could also be typo, you are using `$post_id` instead of `$postid` when setting `$valuepassed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following modifications and adding in die() stopped the script and output whatever the variables value was at that time.

Thanks to @toscho

```
function cf7pp_after_send_mail( $contact_form ) {

    global $postid;

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $postid = $posted_data['_wpcf7'];

        $enable = get_post_meta( $postid, "_cf7pp_enable", true);
        $email = get_post_meta( $postid, "_cf7pp_email", true);

        $valuepassed = get_post_meta($post_id, "_cf7pp_text_menu_b", true);

        if ($enable == "1") {
           // if ($valuepassed == "1") {
                if ($email == "2") {
                      die( $valuepassed );
                //    include_once ('includes/redirect.php');

                    exit;

                }
           // }
        }
    }
}
```